# Why does order matter in this usage of Observable.merge?

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I am trying to write a basic "game loop" using Observables in F#. Basically I conceptualize the fundamental input stream of events as two streams merged together: the key presses of the user (game uses just keyboard to begin with), and the regular ticks of the game (say, 60 times per second).

My problem seems to stem from the fact that one of the observed sequences, i.e. the ticks, is also the loop that calls DispatchEvents() on the Window allowing it to process its inputs and fire key pressed events, so one stream of events is actually driven by the other, if that makes sense. Here is the code:

```
open System;
open System.IO
open SFML.Window
open SFML.Graphics
open System.Reactive
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Diagnostics

type InputEvent =
| Tick of TimeSpan
| KeyPressed of Keyboard.Key

[<EntryPoint;STAThread>]
let main _ = 

    use window = new RenderWindow(VideoMode(640u, 480u), "GameWindow")
    window.SetVerticalSyncEnabled(true)

    let displayStream = 
        Observable.Create(
            fun (observer:IObserver<TimeSpan>) -> 
                let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
                while (window.IsOpen()) do
                    window.DispatchEvents() // this calls the KeyPressed event synchronously
                    window.Display() // this blocks until the next vertical sync
                    window.Clear()
                    observer.OnNext sw.Elapsed
                    sw.Restart()
                observer.OnCompleted();
                { new IDisposable with member this.Dispose() = ()})    

    let onDisplay elapsedTime = 
        // draw game: code elided

    let inputEvents = Observable.merge 
                          (window.KeyPressed |> Observable.map (fun key -> KeyPressed(key.Code)))
                          (displayStream |> Observable.map (fun t -> Tick(t)))
    use subscription = 
        inputEvents.Subscribe(fun inputEvent -> match inputEvent with
                                                | Tick(t) -> onDisplay(t)
                                                | KeyPressed(key) -> printfn "%A" key)

    0
```

This works, however, if I change the order of parameters in Observable.merge:

```
    let inputEvents = Observable.merge 
                          (displayStream |> Observable.map (fun t -> Tick(t)))
                          (window.KeyPressed |> Observable.map (fun key -> KeyPressed(key.Code)))
```

Then the game renders (onDisplay is called), but I don't see KeyPressed events printed to the console. Why is that?

(If you're wondering what is SFML, here's the [link](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml.net/)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In pseudo-code, what merge does is:

```
firstStream.Subscribe(...);
secondStream.Subscribe(...);
```

The subscribe function you pass to `Observable.create` is synchronous and never yields control back to the caller.  This means that `merge` itself is blocked from trying to subscribe to any streams that come after `displayStream`.  When you reorder the streams so that `displayStream` is first, you prevent it from ever subscribing to your `KeyPressed` stream.  This is why you are seeing the behavior you see.

In some respects, your `displayStream` is behaving badly.  `Subscribe` methods should not block.

So, either make sure `displayStream` is the last item in your list, or do some refactoring of your code.  You could just use a `Subject` for `displayStream`.  Then subscribe to everything and finally start the "display loop", where you execute the loop that is currently in your `displayStream` definition and each time through the loop, just call `OnNext` on the subject.

Comment: +1 - great observation - I did not notice the blocking loop in there :(